# How can I set the value of [input type = "file"]?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I aim to ensure that the value of the  field remains unchanged even if the component undergoes any modifications. Presently, the field's value resets whenever I navigate away from the page and subsequently return.

index.js

```js
const Index = () => {
  const renderComponent = (step) => {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return <PersonalDetailsRegistration handlePrev={handlePrev} handleNext={handleNext} stepperValue={step} />;
      case 1:
        return <EducationDetailsRegistration handlePrev={handlePrev} handleNext={handleNext} stepperValue={step} />;
      case 2:
        return <WorkExperienceRegistration handlePrev={handlePrev} handleNext={handleNext} stepperValue={step} />;
      case 3:
        return <SkillSetRegistration handlePrev={handlePrev} handleNext={handleNext} stepperValue={step} />;
      case 4:
        return <UploadDocumentsRegistration handlePrev={handlePrev} handleNext={handleNext} stepperValue={step} />;
      default:
        return <NotFound />;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let comp = renderComponent(step);
    setSelectedComp(comp);
  }, [step]);

  return { selectedComp };
}
```

RHFUploadFile.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import ErrorMessage from './ErrorMessage';

const RHFUploadFile = ({ name, message, defaultValue, ...rest }) => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="file"
        {...register(name)}
        defaultValue={defaultValue} // Set default value here
        {...rest}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} /> {message && <label>{message} </label>}
    </>
  );
};

export default RHFUploadFile;
```

UploadDocumentsRegistration.jsx

```
const UploadDocumentsRegistration = ({ handlePrev, handleNext, stepperValue }) => {
  const { uploadDocumentsRegistration } = useSelector((state) => state?.UploadDocumentsRegistration);

  let defaultValues = {
    id_photo: '',
    dob_certificate: '',
    udegree_certificate: '',
    hpdegree_certificate: '',
    noc_certificate: '',
    id_signature: '',
    place: '',
    checkbox1: false,
    checkbox2: false,
    checkbox3: false,
  };

  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(DocumentsDetailsSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = methods;

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const payload = {
      id_photo: data?.id_photo,
      dob_certificate: data?.dob_certificate,
      udegree_certificate: data?.udegree_certificate,
      hpdegree_certificate: data?.hpdegree_certificate,
      noc_certificate: data?.noc_certificate,
      id_signature: data?.id_signature,
      place: data?.place,
      self_declaration: {
        checkbox1: data?.checkbox1,
        checkbox2: data?.checkbox2,
        checkbox3: data?.checkbox3,
      },
    };
    setDisplayModel(true);
    dispatch(submitUploadDoumentsDetails(payload));
  };

  const handleFileUpload = async (name, event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (!event?.target?.files[0]) {
      if (event?.target?.name == 'id_photo') setProfileImage(null);
      return;
    }
    switch (name) {
      case 'image':
        if (event?.target?.files[0]?.type === 'image/jpeg' || event?.target?.files[0]?.type === 'image/png') {
          if (event?.target?.files[0].size <= 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
            if (event?.target?.name == 'id_photo') setProfileImage(URL?.createObjectURL(event?.target?.files[0]));
            return;
          } else {
            event.target.value = '';
            if (event?.target?.name == 'id_photo') setProfileImage(null);
            setProfileImage(null);
            alert('File must be less than 5MB.');
            return;
          }
        } else {
          event.target.value = '';
          if (event?.target?.name == 'id_photo') setProfileImage(null);
          alert('File must be in Image format.');
          return;
        }
      case 'pdf':
        if (event?.target?.files[0]?.type === 'application/pdf') {
          if (event?.target?.files[0].size <= 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
            return;
          } else {
            event.target.value = '';
            alert('File must be less than 5MB.');
            return;
          }
        } else {
          event.target.value = '';
          alert('File must be in PDF format.');
          return;
        }
        break;
      default:
        alert('Something went wrong');
        return;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('uploadDocumentsRegistration', watch, uploadDocumentsRegistration);
    setValue('checkbox1', uploadDocumentsRegistration && uploadDocumentsRegistration?.self_declaration?.checkbox1);
    setValue('checkbox2', uploadDocumentsRegistration && uploadDocumentsRegistration?.self_declaration?.checkbox2);
    setValue('checkbox3', uploadDocumentsRegistration && uploadDocumentsRegistration?.self_declaration?.checkbox3);
    setValue('place', uploadDocumentsRegistration && uploadDocumentsRegistration?.place);
  }, [setValue, uploadDocumentsRegistration]);

  return (
    <RHFUploadFile
      name="id_photo"
      className="form-control required"
      aria-required="true"
      message="Upload photo of dimensions (4.5 x 3.5 in cms)"
      accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
      onChange={(event) => handleFileUpload('image', event)}
    />
    <RHFUploadFile
      name="dob_certificate"
      id="dob_certificate"
      className="form-control"
      accept="application/pdf"
      onChange={(event) => handleFileUpload('pdf', event)}
    />
  )
}
```

I'm seeking to maintain the current value of the `<input type="file">` field consistently, even after navigating away from the page and returning back. Done anyone have any idea for the same and can help me with this?

Comment: The value of a file input field **can not** be set, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1696877/1427878

Comment: @CBroe and to the 4 users who voted up that comment, you can set the file input field in every browser for years now.

Comment: @Kaiido fair enough, although I'm guessing it will still require additional steps here? (Getting the list of selected files, when the navigation away from the current page happens, so that they are available when the whole thing needs to get restored.)

Comment: @CBroe yeah, I'm not too sure what the exact case is here. I guess they'd need to save to IndexedDB if they want persistance across navigables.

Comment: @DodiTank What's the aim here? If you just want to preserve the `input` element itself, you can give the JSX input element a `ref` so that you can access the actual DOM node when the user picks a file, and then cache that in state while the user does other things, until it's time to submit whatever (compound) form this is part of, and put it (back) in the form prior to submission.